# useMutation update，the cache changed，but UI not change

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I useMutation to send message ,but the message list in chat window not change. I found that the cache has changed . Please help , I can't understand.

The useQuery not work . UI have no change :（

But~! When I put them in one js file. it works.... why???

The version I used is @apollo/react-hooks 3.1.1

Parent window.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { GET_CHAT } from "@/apollo/graphql";
import ChatInput from "@/pages/chat/components/input";

const ChatWindow = (props) => {
  const { chatId, closeChat } = props;
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_CHAT, { variables: { chatId: chatId } });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>{error.message}</p>;

  const { chat } = data;

  return (
    <div className="chatWindow" key={'chatWindow' + chatId}>
      <div className="header">
        <span>{chat.users[1].username}</span>
        <button className="close" onClick={() => closeChat(chatId)}>X</button>
      </div>
      <div className="messages">
        {chat.messages.map((message, j) =>
          <div key={'message' + message.id} className={'message ' + (message.user.id > 1 ? 'left' : 'right')}>
            {message.text}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="input">
        <ChatInput chatId={chatId}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatWindow;
```

Child  input.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useApolloClient, useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { ADD_MESSAGE, GET_CHAT } from "@/apollo/graphql";

const ChatInput = (props) => {
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const { chatId } = props;
  const [addMessage] = useMutation(ADD_MESSAGE, {
    update(cache, { data: { addMessage } }) {
      const { chat } = client.readQuery({
        query: GET_CHAT,
        variables: {
          chatId: chatId
        }
      });
      chat.messages.push(addMessage);
      client.writeQuery({
        query: GET_CHAT,
        variables: {
          chatId: chatId
        },
        data: {
          chat
        }
      });
    }
  });

  const onChangeInput = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTextInput(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (event, chatId, addMessage) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && textInput.length) {
      addMessage({
        variables: {
          message: {
            text: textInput,
            chatId: chatId
          }
        }
      });

      setTextInput('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <input type="text"
           value={textInput}
           onChange={(event) => onChangeInput(event)}
           onKeyPress={(event) => handleKeyPress(event, chatId, addMessage)}
    />
  );
};

export default ChatInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved the issue by now, but for the record:

Your code mutates the chat state:

```
chat.messages.push(addMessage);
```

State should not be mutated (see the React setState Docs for more details).
Contruct a new array instead:

```
const newChat = [...chat, addMessage]
```